# Celery Task discovery in Django App only partially working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I have a rather odd issue with task discovery only functioning partially in a Django app.

I have an app with structure like:

```
app\
 |>celery.py
  >tasks\
   |>__init__.py
   |>a.py
   |>b.py
   |>c.py
```

celery.py:

```py
class CeleryAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'taskapp'
    verbose_name = 'Celery Config'

    def ready(self):
        installed_apps = [app_config.name for app_config in apps.get_app_configs()]
        app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: installed_apps, force=True)
```

Init.py:

```py
from .a import *
from .b import *
from .c import *
```

a.py b.py & c.py@

```py
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(bind=True)
def Task(self):
    #do stuff.
```

The issue is that although tasks in a.py and b.py are autodiscovered, tasks in c.py aren't.

Copying a function from c.py to a.py means it's recognised, and the reverse not.

Ultimately I can make it work without having tasks in multiple files, but its super annoying. I'm running python 3.6 on alpine with django 2 and celery 4.2